# How to join multiple columns together on blanks of one column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

This is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(option_1 = c("Box 1", "", ""), option_2 = c("", 4, ""), Width = c("","",3))
```

I want to get this data frame:

```
  option_1
1    Box 1
2        4
3        3
```

I'm doing this on a much bigger dataframe with 5+ columns I'm merging on blanks with respect to the option_1 column. I have tried using coalesce, but some of the columns won't "merge" on the blanks. For example:

```
df %>%
mutate(option_value_1 = coalesce(option_value_1, option_value_2, option_value_3, option_value_4, option_value_5, option_value_6, option_value_7))
```

option_value_5 wouldn't come together with option_value_1 on the blanks, but the other option values did. Should I put the vectors in a list then use coalesce?

Answer (score 0):

We convert the blank (`""`) to `NA` and `coalesce` with the bang-bang (`!!!`) operator. According to `?"!!!"`

> The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The elements of the list are spliced in place, meaning that they each become one single argument.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  na_if("") %>%
  transmute(option_1 = coalesce(!!! .))
```

-output

```
  option_1
1    Box 1
2        4
3        3
```

---

If we are interested only in the 'option' columns, subset the columns (also can use `invoke` with `coalesce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  na_if("") %>%
   mutate(option_1 = invoke(coalesce, 
        across(starts_with("option"))), .keep = "unused")
```

Answer (score 0):

With a base R approach:

```r
df <- data.frame(option_1 = apply(df, 1, \(x) paste(x, collapse = "")))

df

#>   option_1
#> 1    Box 1
#> 2        4
#> 3        3
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  transmute(option_1 = str_c(c_across(everything()), collapse = "")) %>% 
  ungroup
```